# How do I restart my program without restarting the variable declarations

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, openweathermap

I'm still making my weather app and I need a function to change the City or Country, The problem is that I have to restart the program to display the changes but when I do restart- The default city gets loaded instead of the new one, I have tried many ways to fix this but they all didn't work, Thanks in advance!

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
#Please don't use my API-KEY for bad purposes, I have only included it to help run the code
import requests, json
from tkinter import *
import os
CITY = "Glasgow"
BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=+" + CITY + "&units=metric&APPID=confedential"
response = requests.get(URL)

def func() :
    def change():
        y = Toplevel()
        y.geometry("200x100")
        en = Entry(y, width=10)
        en.place(x=25, y=25)
        en.focus()

        def getr(e):
            def restart():
                x.destroy()
                func()

            CITY = en.get()
            restart()

        en.bind("<Return>", getr)
    if response.status_code == 200:

        data = response.json()
        main = data['main']
        temperature = main['temp']
        humidity = main['humidity']
        pressure = main['pressure']
        report = data['weather']
        print(f"{CITY:-^30}")
        print(f"Temperature: {temperature}")
        print(f"Humidity: {humidity}")
        print(f"Pressure: {pressure}")
        print(f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}")

        rep = report[0]['main'].lower()

        if "clear" in rep:
            image = 'images/sunny.png'
        if "cloud" in rep:
            image = 'images/cloud.png'
        if "rain" in rep:
            image = 'images/rain.png'
        if "thunder" in rep:
            image = 'images/thunder.png'
        if "mist" in rep:
            image = 'images/mist.png'
        if "snow" in rep:
            image = 'images/snow.png'

        x = Tk()
        # Creating Menubar
        menubar = Menu(x)
        menubar.config(bg="#484848", fg="white", font=("Stencil Std", 10))

        # Adding Help Menu
        help_ = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg="#484848", fg="white", font=("Stencil Std", 10))
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Countries', menu=help_)
        help_.add_command(label='Change Current Country', command=change)
        help_.add_command(label='Show Current Country', command=None)
        help_.add_separator()
        help_.add_command(label='Change Timezone', command=None)
        help_.add_command(label='Show Current Timezone', command=None)
        help_.add_separator()
        help_.add_command(label="Exit", command=x.destroy)

        # display Menu
        x.config(menu=menubar)
        x.resizable(False, False)
        gif = PhotoImage(file=image)
        cvwid = gif.width()
        cvhei = gif.height()
        canvas = Canvas(x, width=cvwid, height=cvhei, bg='lightblue')
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)

        img = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=gif, anchor=NW)

        temp = canvas.create_text(cvwid / 2, 350, fill="White", font="Helvetica 30", text=str(int(temperature)) + "°C")
        reportr = canvas.create_text(cvwid / 2, 400, fill="White", font="Helvetica 20", text=report[0]["main"])
        x.title(f"{CITY:-^30}")
        x.mainloop()

func()
```

Comment: Why do you have so many nested functions? There are global variables for a reason. Also have you tried putting the `URL = ...` and the `response = ...` inside a function that you can call to get the updated information?

Comment: If someone is dishonest enough to use your key, asking them nicely is not a winning strategy. You need to remove those credentials ASAP, and you might want to contact a moderator to have it removed from the question history.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign `response = requests.get(URL)` only once. No matter how often you change the city, the response that was established with the parameter `"Glasgow"` will always stay the same.

The fastest fix without refactoring the whole codebase would be to make `CITY` and `response` global so you can modify them from within a function. For example:

```
CITY = "Glasgow"
URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=+{}&units=metric&APPID=confidential"

def get_response(city=CITY):
    return requests.get(URL.format(city))

response = get_response()
```

Then you could global your variables in your `getr(e)` function like this.

```
def getr(e):                 
    global CITY, response
    CITY = en.get()
    response = get_response(CITY)
    restart()
```

This is a solution to the problem you currently have. However I would suggest, to go back to your codebase. With a good refactor you would not need this: You could think about seperating logic and ui, make your functions accept parameters and seperate them from each other, research how to update/change display values within a running Tk() mainloop instead of destroying and recalling it. Maybe it would help, to post your code on [stackexchange for codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).